# How to get the data from the Mainactivity.java to the adapter.java for its textview .setText for viewing?

Tags: java, android

Problem on getting data from MainActivity.java to Yearamountadapter.java.

What code should i write in order retrieve data from the Mainactivity into the Yearamountadapter.java?

I have tried to use the intent method to retrive data from mainactivity.java to Yearamountadapter.java but the getIntent shows red.

This is Mainactivity.java which extends AppCompactActivity

```
float FVend = (float)(PMT * ((basepwr - 1) / (r/100*n))); //end formula
                    float totalmethodend = CI + FVend;

                    String noyears = Double.toString(t);
                    String end = Float.toString(totalmethodend); //end compound

                    //Below coding To transfer data end and noyears to Yearamountadapter line 48&49 .setText
                    //Using noyears as increment for loop at Activity 2
                    Intent gotoyearamountadapter = new Intent( MainActivity.this, com.app.compoundinginterestproject.Yearamountadapter.class);
                    gotoyearamountadapter.putExtra("end", end);
                    gotoyearamountadapter.putExtra("noyears", noyears);
                    startActivity(gotoyearamountadapter);

                    Intent gotoactivity2 = new Intent( MainActivity.this, com.app.compoundinginterestproject.Activity2.class);
                    gotoactivity2.putExtra("end", end);
                    gotoactivity2.putExtra("noyears", noyears);
                    startActivity(gotoactivity2);


                }


            }
        });
    }


}
```

This is Yearamountadapter.java which extends ArrayAdapter

```
  TextView tvnumberofyears = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1) ;
        TextView tvtotals = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        String years = getIntent.getStringExtra("noyears"); //could not get intent from MainActivity
        int year = Integer.parseInt(years);

        String totals = getIntent(). getStringExtra("end"); //could not get intent from MainActivity
        float total = float.parseFloat(totals);

        tvnumberofyears.setText(year);/* to get number of years increment base on the compute onclicklistener*/
        tvtotals.setText(total);/*to get the total increment bast on the compute onclicklistener*/

        return convertView;

    }

}
```

After I got the data from the Mainactivity, I expect the be able set the tvnumberofyears and tvtotals.setText to view in the list

Comment: You're missing () on the first getIntent() and you have a space after () in the second getIntent(). Check again after correcting them.

Comment: Still the same error after input brackets (). Errors are same for both years and totals getintents() marked red